# How do I calculate the probability of reaching mean residual life

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I need to understand the Survival Analysis concept of "mean residual life (MRL)" and calculating probabilities for reaching it.

From another
[discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104494/mean-residual-life-clarification-needed):

> The MRL at time t is the mean additional time after time t that you
>   expect an entity to survive, given that it has survived until time t.
>   It does not include the time from time 0 to time t that the entity has
>   already lived through, so it is possible for it to be less than the
>   mean lifetime if t>0. It must equal the mean lifetime if t=0.

I've worked up a Manipulate model to illustrate some of this:

```
 MRL[variable_, distribution_] := 
  NExpectation[X \[Conditioned] X > variable, 
    X \[Distributed] distribution] - variable;

mrlPlot = Plot[
   MRL[x, LogNormalDistribution[1.75, 0.65]], {x, 0, 40},
   ImageSize -> 400,
   PlotRange -> All,
   AxesLabel -> {"Time", None}, ImagePadding -> {{20, 40}, {10, 0}}];

Manipulate[ 
 Module[{mrl, dist, mean, cdf, cdfMean, cdfMRL, pdf, pdfMRL, 
   pdfMean},
  dist = LogNormalDistribution[1.75, 0.65];
  mrl = MRL[t , dist] + t;
  mean = Mean[dist];
  cdf = N[CDF[dist, t], 3];
  cdfMRL = N[CDF[dist, mrl], 3];
  cdfMean = N[CDF[dist, mean], 3];
  pdf = N[PDF[dist, t ], 3];
  pdfMRL = N[PDF[dist, mrl], 3];
  pdfMean = N[PDF[dist, mean], 3];

  Column[{
    "PDF",
    Show[
     {
      Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, 0, 40},
       ImageSize -> 400,
       PlotRange -> All,
       AxesLabel -> {"Time", None}, 
       ImagePadding -> {{20, 40}, {10, 0}},
       Prolog -> {Text["Expectation", {mean + 3.5, .01}], 
         Text["t", {t + 1, pdf - .003}], 
         Text["MRL+t", {mrl + 3, pdfMRL - .003}]}],
      Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, t, mean}, PlotRange -> All, 
       AxesOrigin -> {Automatic, 0}, Filling -> Axis],
      ListPlot[{{t, pdf}, {mean, pdfMRL}}, PlotRange -> All, 
       PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.015]],
      ListPlot[{{mrl, pdfMRL}}, PlotRange -> All, 
       PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.015]}]
      },
     GridLines -> {{{t, {Dashed}}, {mean, {Dashed, 
          LightGray}}, {mrl, {Dashed, Red}}}, {{pdfMean, LightGray}, 
        pdf, pdfMRL}}],
    "", "CDF",
    Show[{
      Plot[CDF[dist, x], {x, 0, 40},
       ImageSize -> 400,
       PlotRange -> All,
       AxesLabel -> {"Times", None}, 
       ImagePadding -> {{20, 40}, {10, 0}},
       Prolog -> {Text["Expectation", {mean + 3.5, .075}], 
         Text["t", {t + 1, cdf - .03}], 
         Text["MRL+t", {mrl + 3, cdfMRL - .03}]}],
      ListPlot[{{t, cdf}, {mean, cdfMean}}, PlotRange -> All, 
       PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.015]],
      ListPlot[{{mrl, cdfMRL}}, PlotRange -> All, 
       PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.015]}]},
     GridLines -> {{{t, {Dashed}}, {mean, {Dashed, 
          LightGray}}, {mrl, {Dashed, Red}}}, {{cdfMean, LightGray}, 
        cdf, cdfMRL}}],
    "", "MEAN RESIDUAL LIFE",
    mrlPlot
    }]],
 {{t, 0, "t"}, 0, 40, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {t},
 FrameLabel -> {None, None, 
   "SURVIVAL ANALYSIS & MEAN RESIDUAL LIFE"},
 LabelStyle -> Medium]
```

Snapshot of the Manipulate follows:

[image: snapshot]

The last of the plots in the Manipulate[] shows a static plot of mean residual life.  You can see how at time, t = 0 its value is just over 7 which equals the mean lifetime (expectation).  It shows how MRL drops then rises as t varies from 0 to 40.

The PDF and CDF plots show something else, t + MRL, or how much the person has lived until now (t) plus the mean of the lifetime remaining to it.

Given the timeframe shown (0 to 40) t + MRL will vary its distance as t increases, but will always remain beyond t.  I think this makes sense, given that someone or something has survived to some point, t, and has no absolute limit of life, they have some additional time to live.

1st question: Does this make sense so far?  Just working my way through these ideas, so I may not have them all right just yet.

2nd question: *I now need to calculate the probability of someone reaching t + MRL given that they have already reached t*.

This seems like it should be straight forward, but I don't have a good intuition for the answer.  I've thought I could do one of these:

```
MRL[variable_, distribution_] := NExpectation[X \[Conditioned] X > variable, X \[Distributed] distribution] - variable;
t = 5;
expectedLife = MRL[t, LogNormalDistribution[1.75, 0.65]] + t

p1 = NProbability[x >= t && x <= expectedLife, x \[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[1.75, 0.65]]
p2 = NProbability[x <= expectedLife, x \[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[1.75, 0.65]]
```

Does either p1 or p2 makes sense?  Have I missed something fundamental here?  How should I go about this?

Any help and explanation much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This topic is a bit unfamiliar to me but here's my take. I believe you can simplify your life a bit by looking at an alternative definition of mrl.

Using the definition for continuous distributions...

```
Expectation[x - t \[Conditioned] x > t, x \[Distributed] dist] ==
Expectation[x - t, x \[Distributed] TruncatedDistribution[{t, Infinity}, dist]] ==
Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] TruncatedDistribution[{t, Infinity}, dist]] - t
```

giving us...

```
 mrl[t_] = Mean[TruncatedDistribution[{t, Infinity}, dist]] - t
```

This gives an easy way to obtain another measure which, according to [Klein and Moeschberger](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038795399X) (a book I highly recommend), is preferable for skewed distributions. This is the median residual life:

```
mdrl[t_] =  Median[TruncatedDistribution[{t, Infinity}, dist]] - t
```

For fun, lets compare them for `dist = LogNormalDistribution[1.75, .65]`.

```
Plot[{mrl[t], mdrl[t]}, {t, 0, 40}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image: plots of mean and median residual lives]

Now the probability that someone survives mrl (or mdrl) units beyond time `t` given they have survived to time `t` is relatively easy to compute in that we can state it exactly as we say it.

```
pMRL[t_] := NProbability[x > t + mrl[t] \[Conditioned] x > t, x \[Distributed] dist]
pMDRL[t_] := NProbability[x > t + mdrl[t] \[Conditioned] x > t, x \[Distributed] dist]
```

Not surprisingly, the plot for `pMDRL` is not very exciting compared to `pMRL`.

```
Plot[{pMRL[t], pMDRL[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image: plots of probability of mean and median residual lives]

Comment: Really helpful.  Still absorbing this.  Thought a Timing[] of the 4 ways to do it that you show would prove interesting: t=5, dist as above. Timing[Expectation[x - t \[Conditioned] x > t, 
  x \[Distributed] dist]]
Timing[Expectation[x - t, 
  x \[Distributed] TruncatedDistribution[{t, Infinity}, dist]]]
Timing[Expectation[x, 
   x \[Distributed] TruncatedDistribution[{t, Infinity}, dist]] - t]
Timing[Mean[TruncatedDistribution[{t, Infinity}, dist]] - t]
{8.08079, 4.79343} {0.764908, 4.79343} {0.362332, 4.79343} {0.443986, 4.79343}.  Any idea of why the 3rd way runs so much faster?

Comment: I suspect its because something very much like the third method is what is actually being done under the hood for the others so it circumvents some logic, simplification, and checking to call it directly. This is just a suspicion though.